# Error when getting list_unsampled_reports using RGA

Tags: r, google-analytics-api

I am using the RGA package to connect R and Google Analytics: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RGA/RGA.pdf

I am trying to get the list of unsampled reports created for a view using:

```
list_unsampled_reports(account.id, webproperty.id, profile.id,
start.index = NULL, max.results = NULL, token)
```

It prompts the following error: 
"Error: client error: (400) Bad Request
  reason            message                           locationType location
1 invalid parameter Invalid field selection segmentId parameter    fields"

Can anyone advise?

Comment: What are the values of `account.id`, `webproperty.id`...?

Comment: Have you made sure the account and username you are authenticating with you are accessing has access to unsampled reports?

Comment: @Pascal: It's confidential so I can't put it up here, but an example is: 

`list_unsampled_reports('7777777', 'UA-7777777-1', '88888888', start.index = NULL, max.results = NULL, ga_token)`

the authentication is done via: 

library (RGA)
authorize(client.id = "xxx", client.secret = "xxx")
ga_token <- authorize(client.id = "xxx", client.secret = "xxx")

The other _list syntax works well, for e.g:
get_goal('7777777', 'UA-7777777-1', '88888888', '4')

I have accessed to unsampled reports from interface as well. Not sure why segmentID is part of the error then ....

Comment: Client Login is deprecated and should not be used. See my answer below for links to the appropriate resources to get OAuth 2.0 working.

Answer (score 0):

Client Login is [deprecated](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/04/a-final-farewell-to-clientlogin-oauth.html), you should use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

There is a recently updated [Hello Analytics API tutoria](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/installed-py)l that should guide you through the steps to get your application working.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by a bug when specifying fields in the request to API (`segmentId` instead `webPropertyId`). This bug is already [fixed](https://bitbucket.org/unikum/rga/commits/6a9044731ed9).